# How to click Search key on the keyboard of an ios device to automate a webapp using selenium?

Tags: ios, selenium, keyboard-events, appium-ios

Application Type: Web App

Device: IOS(iPAD)

Browser: Safari

I am trying to search a incident in the search box but the only option I can do it is by clicking the 'Search' key on the keyboard after entering incident id. I am able to enter the incident id using `sendkeys()` but not getting how to click the 'Search' key on the keyboard.

I have tried the below things for this:

```
1.  SEARCHBOX.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ENTER));

2.  SEARCHBOX.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.RETURN));

3.  SEARCHBOX.sendKeys("\n");

4.  SEARCHBOX.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

5.  Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

but non of them worked.

Comment: SEARCHBOX.sendkeys(keys.ENTER); <- is this working?

Comment: No, it didn't work.

Comment: String command = "adb -s input keyevent KEYCODE_SEARCH";
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

Comment: I guess this command is for native app and not for webapp running in the safari browser of a mobile device. Tried it but didn't work.

Comment: open the keyboard and just give a try. It has to work for both

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```